# Getting 400 bad request from Microsoft Graph Api for SchemaExtensions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-api-management, microsoft365

**Limit of: 5 extension schema definitions can be written. !**

Here is the response

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Limit of: 5 extension schema definitions can be written.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-10-26T12:29:47",
        "request-id": "requestID",
        "client-request-id": "client-requestID"
    }
}
```

}

And here is the request body

```
{
"id": "myMetaData",
"description": "My description",
"targetTypes": [
    "Group"
],
"properties": [
    {
        "name": "shortName",
        "type": "String"
    },
    {
        "name": "supervisor",
        "type": "String"
    }
]
```

}

I have used delegated permision and used token generated by password since SchemaExtension needs delegated one and doesn't support application perm.

Comment: Can you please provide the correlation id and its respective timestamp

Comment: sorry I got the answer , it was due to limit of the schemaExtensions that could be created other developer on the project already created 5 and since this was the limit set it showed this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer , it was due to limit of the schemaExtensions that could be created other developer on the project already created 5 and since this was the limit set it showed this error